# How Does Droid's Exchange Connector Work?

Tags: email, exchange, cellular

TL;DR:

[flow chart http://img2.pict.com/6e/d6/a7/2101822/0/mockup.png](http://img2.pict.com/6e/d6/a7/2101822/0/mockup.png)

---

I'm curious about how email flows into the Droid handset from my corporate MS Exchange server. If I run through the regular Exchange config wizard and configure it to talk directly to my company's server, does it flow directly from my server to my device or does it still (somehow) route through a third party first (e.g. Google or Verizon)?

Also, how can I tell if it is securely transmitted (e.g. SSL)? Is this all the same when sending mail from Droid, too?

+1 if you have references!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page on Wired](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2009/11/verizon-droid-exchange/) answers both questions indirectly:

> Droid supports Microsoft Exchange’s
>   ActiveSync feature that lets users
>   access e-mail, calendar and contacts
>   from their corporate servers running
>   Exchange.

**ActiveSync** is the protocol used to talk to Exchange Server directly.  In order to use ActiveSync over the Internet the way Droid and other handsets do, they have to support Outlook Anywhere, which is always encrypted by default.